# Apollo Server + mongoose, passing createdBy, updatedBy to every update/insert/delete operation

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to pass `createdBy` and `updatedBy` information to every query with `mongoose`. Is there any way to do this using middlewares with express and/or Apollo Graphql?

I then will use mongoose.set to send debug information to our logging server.

Comment: Did you try passing info in Apollo server context and then set the same info in each resolver to further save in mongodb. Because we use mutations only for insert/update/delete operations, so it is hard to indentify what the opration is and should createdBy be updated or not.

Comment: Hi Vikram, I solved this issue with AsyncLocalStorage implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using `AsyncLocalStorage` implementation.

this is my threadContext implementation

```
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');

const localStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const contextInit = {
  user: null,
  environment: process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV || 'local',
  sourceCompany: undefined,
};

const getContext = () => localStorage.getStore();

const initializeContext = (additionalContext) => localStorage.enterWith({ ...contextInit, ...additionalContext });

const updateContext = (context) => {
  Object.keys(context).forEach((k) => {
    localStorage.getStore()[k] = context[k];
  });
};

module.exports = {
  getContext,
  contextInit,
  initializeContext,
  updateContext,
};
```

then, I injected middleware to initialize the context to express

```
const { initializeContext: initializeThreadContext } = require('./services/threadContext');

const RequestId = require('./helpers/expressRequestId');

app.use(RequestId()); <<-- feel free to write your own
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  initializeThreadContext({ requestId: req.id });
  next();
});
```

In apollo server `context` to store user data

```
// include user in threadContext
threadContext.getContext().user = user ? { _id: user._id, name: user.name } : undefined;
```

then in `mongoose`, I am logging our queries with user data

```
mongoose.set('debug', (collectionName, methodName, query, doc, ...methodArgs) => {
  const ignoredMethods = [/createIndex/, /watch/];
  if (ignoredMethods.some((m) => new RegExp(m).test(methodName))) return;

  logger.debug(`Mongodb operation '${methodName}' on  '${collectionName}'`, {
    collectionName,
    methodName,
    query,
    ...threadContext.getContext(),
  });
});
```

I preferred not to store user info with createdBy instead logged it